# R - Check for same values in two different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have a data frame (data) that looks like this. Dataframe for test of COVID:

```
> ID        DATE           Result
  1        1/11/2020       POSITIVE
  2        1/11/2020       NEGATIVE
  2        2/11/2020       POSITIVE
  3        2/11/2020       POSITIVE
  3        3/11/2020       NEGATIVE
```

Then I have another data frame (data_new) that looks like this, which is only the POSITIVE results

```
> ID        DATE           Result
  1        1/11/2020       POSITIVE
  2        2/11/2020       POSITIVE
  3        2/11/2020       POSITIVE
```

The original dataset are very big.
My wish is to find a code that will take "data_new" and look back in "data" to find if the same ID appears in "data" and have taken a test before the date of positive result.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% left_join(df1, by = 'ID') %>% filter((DATE.x > DATE.y) & Result.x == 'POSITIVE')
# A tibble: 1 x 5
     ID DATE.x     Result.x DATE.y     Result.y
  <dbl> <date>     <chr>    <date>     <chr>   
1     2 2020-11-02 POSITIVE 2020-11-01 NEGATIVE
```

Data used:

```
df1
# A tibble: 5 x 3
     ID DATE       Result  
  <dbl> <date>     <chr>   
1     1 2020-11-01 POSITIVE
2     2 2020-11-01 NEGATIVE
3     2 2020-11-02 POSITIVE
4     3 2020-11-02 POSITIVE
5     3 2020-11-03 NEGATIVE
df2
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID DATE       Result  
  <dbl> <date>     <chr>   
1     1 2020-11-01 POSITIVE
2     2 2020-11-02 POSITIVE
3     3 2020-11-02 POSITIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have similar column names I'll suggest renaming the column names before joining the data. For each `ID` then you can check if they have taken a test before the date of positive result.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  rename(test_date = DATE) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% 
              rename(positive_date = DATE, final_result = Result), by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(across(c(test_date, positive_date), lubridate::dmy)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(test_before = any(first(positive_date) > test_date))

#    ID test_before
#  <int> <lgl>      
#1     1 FALSE      
#2     2 TRUE       
#3     3 FALSE
```